# what is the possibility of not unique id in a loop

Tags: php

I'm looping through an array and for each record generating unique identifier with `uniqid`:

```
foreach($emailsByCampaign as $campaign => $emails) {
    $campaignHex = $this->strToHex($campaign);
    $values = "(";
    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($emails);$i++) {
        $values .= $analyticsDbInstance->escape($emails[$i]) . ",'" . uniqid(true) . "'), (";
    }
}
```

Official documentation states that `uniqid` generates `id` based on microseconds. What is the likely that two cycles of the loop will pass in less than two seconds which will lead to not unique ids?

Comment: We don't know how fast your server is. You will need to characterize this for yourself.

Comment: So calculation is pretty easy here, right? If the server can process loops faster then microseconds go, then there will be duplicates?

Comment: This link will be useful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070110/how-unique-is-uniqid

Comment: add $i as a character to the result?

Comment: @AlexK., thanks, I've decided to add $i as well.

Answer (score 4):

`uniqid()` generates a value based on the number of microseconds since the start of the Unix epoch - 1st January 1970. On a single machine every ID will be unique. It is possible (but unlikely) that two separate machines might generate the same `uniqid()` in which case the prefix and entropy parameters can be used to avoid this.

There are a number of implementations of UUID (or GUID) in PHP, but these generally generate V4 UUIDs, which aren't guaranteed to be unique (but the probability of a collision is vanishingly small)

If you need to generate something more secure you can use [openssl-random-pseudo-bytes()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php)

Comment: _On a single machine every ID will be unique_ regardless of the time it takes to go one loop? I'll be using one machine only so if the uniqueness is guaranteed, `unique` is enough.