# How easily will uniqid() with more entropy create a duplicate?

Tags: php, unique-id

This might be an off topic question but i hope someone can answer this question.

Per how many nanoseconds, mili seconds or seconds does uniqid() with more entropy run the risk of creating a duplicate?

With reference to link below, uniqid will collide if two id are created in one milisecond. What about with more entropy?

(My goal is to use a small indexable alphanumeric string as document id at creation that can be created fast with minimum processor power without db interference.)

Answers here dont seem to provide any exact number: 
[How unique is uniqid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070110/how-unique-is-uniqid)

Comment: That may be an off topic, but have you looked at uuid v4 ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15875555/4099089

Comment: Actually `uniqid` without `more_entropy` will do an `usleep(1)` so it is never going to return the same value twice (within the same thread, anyway):
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/1c295d4a9ac78fcc2f77d6695987598bb7abcb83/ext/standard/uniqid.c#L68

Comment: That said, if duplicate IDs are a serious risk, you probably should not use `uniqid`. And if they aren't, just detect duplicates and recover from them.

Comment: @Tgr please consider adding your comments as answer. Will mark it as the answer to the main problem in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/1c295d4a9ac78fcc2f77d6695987598bb7abcb83/ext/standard/uniqid.c), `more_entropy` adds nine random decimal digits, so you can expect a collision after 37,000 or so calls. (For how a billion turned into 37,000, see the [birthday attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack).) That of course ignores the fact that these digits are not actually random but generated by an [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), and the same LCG is probably used in other places in the code, so the actual chance of collision is probably higher (by how much exactly, I have no idea).

Also worth noting that `uniqid` does not actually guarantee microsecond resolution as some PHP implementations (Windows, specifically) don't have access to a microsecond-precision clock.

In short, if you need a unique ID for anything security-sensitive, or collisions are costly, avoid `uniqid`. Otherwise, using it with `more_entropy` is probably fine (although the common pattern is to use `uniqid(mt_rand(), true)` to add even more extra entropy).